# rsyslog is creating empty directories

Tags: centos, logs, syslog, rsyslog

I have the following rsyslog configurations.

SYSLOG MASTER(centos 7.x):

```
[root@SYSLOGMASTER ~]# egrep -i "UDP|TCP|template" /etc/rsyslog.conf -A3
# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

$template remote-incoming-logs, "/var/log/RemoteLogs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
if $fromhost !='SYSLOGMASTER' then -?remote-incoming-logs
& stop
```

SYSLOG CLIENT

```
[root@SYSLOG-CLIENT ~]# egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/rsyslog.conf
$PreserveFQDN on
$template FileFormatMillisec,"%TIMESTAMP%%TIMESTAMP:20:23:date-rfc3339% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate FileFormatMillisec
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
$OmitLocalLogging off
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local0.none;local1.none;local2.none                    -/var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log
local0.*                                                -/var/log/app/app.log
$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0
$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off
local1.*                -/var/log/app/api.http.log
local2.*                -/var/log/app/app.http.log
*.* @@172.24.34.118:514
[root@SYSLOG-CLIENT ~]#
```

There isn't any configuration inside /etc/rsyslog.d/*.

The issue here is, rsyslog is creating weird directories, inside the '/var/log/RemoteLogs" path. What I found is, these directory names are from log files, which are being shipped from the client-server to master. Below are the examples directories (09-01,09-02,129,138,147,165 etc. etc.):

```
[root@SYSLOGMASTER RemoteLogs]# ll
total 4
drwx------ 2 root root   34 Sep  1 23:08 09-01
drwx------ 2 root root  146 Sep  2 09:08 09-02
drwx------ 2 root root   19 Sep  1 23:18 129
drwx------ 2 root root   19 Sep  1 23:33 138
drwx------ 2 root root   19 Sep  1 23:48 147
drwx------ 2 root root   19 Sep  2 00:18 165
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Sep  2 08:48 172.24.34.104
drwx------ 2 root root  118 Sep  1 20:12 172.24.34.108
```

Any advice on this is much appreciated.